Do we have any proof of hadiths?
Assalamualaikum, i have a question please answer, in the Quran it never mentions anything about "hadiths" and "Sunnah" is not also mentioned, the word Sunnah is mentioned but it doesn't refer to "things prophet Muhammad used to do" it refers to something else, also we dont have any proof of the hadith books, the Quran never mentions the word Hadith or Sunnah, if we dont have any proof of hadiths why do we follow them? We do have proof of the Quran, it was a book by Allah, but Allah never commands us anything about "hadiths" or "sunnahs" in the Quran, and the hadith books (Sahih Bukhari, Sahih Muslim, Sunan abu Dawud ibn Majah, jamia tirmidhi) we dont have any proof like the person who wrote it where did he/she got the information or proof that Prophet Muhammad actually said these things or did those things or not? And the person who wrote it was just a normal human being and these books were written 100+ years after Prophet Muhammad (SAW)'s death, so where did they got the proof that the Prophet said or did those things?? If you have any proof or answer to my question please reply.

What even do you mean by "proof"? I doubt you've ever met the prophet Muhammad yourself, yet you seem fairly confident that he existed and revealed the Qur'an. Even 1400+ years after the fact.

If you didnt read my question dont comment, and i said that the hadith books were written 100-300+ years after the prophets death where did they got the information after 100-300 years, if you dont know how to answer my question dont comment

Yes i do believe that he existed before 1400 years lol, we have the Quran and that was written 1400 years ago with the same words nothing changed and in the Quran Allah says that it was revealed by Muhammad. I suggest you to read the question before commenting

The qur'an is the word of Allah it isn't written but memorized and orally transmitted from teacher to student since the time of the Prophet. The physical book you may use is a Moshaf not a qur'an. Secondly the same standards for qur'an transmission are valid fro sahih hadith. Thirdly if you further claim that you  don't believe the truth of (all) hadith and sunnah and believe in the sira and history books this would be a huge issue.

Some relevant questions Isthe quran compelet? If so why do we need hadith?, What is the ruling regarding hadith rejecters? and Is there any reason to not follow only the quran and reject the sunnah?

Salam. To answer your question I have referred these two links as I am not an expert in this topic.This is a link from quora
and this is a link from islam stack exchange itself. This wil give a overall idea.
As a new contributor I understand your immaturity in asking such a question and commenting in such a childish way.
Its expected of you that you research at least a bit on the topics you ask the questions.
Please be respectful next time.
